# How to rspec join record in many-to-many in rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the create in rfq controller:

```
  def create
    if has_create_right?
      @rfq = Rfq.new(params[:rfq], :as => :roles_new )
      #save into join table rfqs_standards
      params[:rfq][:standard_ids].each do |sid|
        @rfq.standards << Standard.find(sid.to_i) if !sid.nil?
      end
    if @rfq.save
        redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")
      else
        flash.now[:error] = "RFQ not saved!"
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the rspec code

```
  describe "'create'" do
    it "should be successful for corp head" do
      session[:corp_head] = true
      session[:user_id] = 1
      s = Factory(:standard)
      rfq = Factory.attributes_for(:rfq)
      rfq.standards << s
      get 'create', :rfq => rfq
      response.should redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")
    end
  end
```

The error is:

```
  1) RfqsController 'create' should be successful for corp head
     Failure/Error: rfq.standards << s
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `standards' for #<Hash:0x6741570>
     # ./spec/controllers/rfqs_controller_spec.rb:65:in `block (3 levels) in <top (requi
```

What's the right way to test join record? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this part of your test:

```
    rfq = Factory.attributes_for(:rfq)
    rfq.standards << s
```

it would seem that rfq is created as an attributes hash and not a complete model. You can try joining the standard_ids like this:

```
describe "'create'" do
  it "should be successful for corp head" do
    session[:corp_head] = true
    session[:user_id] = 1
    s = Factory(:standard)
    rfq = Factory.attributes_for(:rfq)
    rfq[:standard_ids] = [s.id] # attach standard_id's to mimic the POST'ed form data
    get 'create', :rfq => rfq
    response.should redirect_to URI.escape("/view_handler?index=0&msg=RFQ saved!")
  end
end
```

However, it seems that you can accomplish all of this using nested attributes - see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: The app has no problem to save into join table when a new rfq is saved. Now the issue is how to rspec it. Here is a post about how to save into join table - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736805/how-to-save-2-id-in-joint-table-for-many-to-many-relationship-in-rails-3-1.

Comment: Agreed, but the code I posted above is not how to save the model, but rather how to fix your RSpec test (I've updated to make it more clear).  The comment about nested attributes was simply a remark/suggestion about how you are implementing the saving of the joined models.  You are correct that for a habtm relationship, nested attributes won't work as well, but it wasn't clear that you were talking about a habtm from your OP.

Comment: Just tested it and failed. The error is :     Failure/Error: get 'create', :rfq => rfq
     NoMethodError:
       You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!               The problem seems to be the same which is rfq (attributes_for) is not an object. In rails console, if rfq is crated as an object, then rfq.standards << s would execute without error. The create code seems OK to create a new rfq. However the rspec code failed. Now sure how rfq.new(params[:rfq]) could be treated as rfq object in controller execution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: rfq[:standard_ids] = [s.id] seems to be a right way to go. The case passed. Not sure why it did not pass the first time. Thanks,